# Add typing hints to linkedlist's top method

Tags: python, linked-list

I am learning the linked list implemented in Python:

```
$ cat linked_stack.py 
class LinkedStack:
    """LIFO Stack implementation using a singly linked list for storage"""
    #-------------nested Node class ------------------------------------
    class _Node:
        """Lightweight, nonpublic class for storing a singly linked node."""
        __slots__ = "_element", "_next"

        def __init__(self, element, next): #initialize node's fields
            self._element = element
            self._next = next
    #--------------stack methods---------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Create an empty stack"""
        self._head = None
        self._size = 0

    def top(self):
        """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.
        Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty."""
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Exception("Stack is empty")
        return self._head._element


    def __len__(self)->int:
        return self._size


    def is_empty(self)->bool:
        return len(self._size) == 0


    def push(self, e) -> None:
        self._head = self._Node(e, self._head) #create and link a new node
        self._size += 1


    def pop(self)
```

Reference to the top method is:

```
def top(self):
    """Return (but do not remove) the element at the top of the stack.
    Raise Empty exception if the stack is empty."""
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Exception("Stack is empty")
    return self._head._element
```

I want to annotate it as:

```
def top(self)-> _Node._element:
```

How to get it done in a decent way?

Comment: `_Node._element` isn't a type. Using it as a type annotation doesn't make sense.

Comment: You did not type annotate `element` in the `Node` constructor, so what type do you expect elements to be?

Comment: You want generics